# VBA - Excel Delay and Forcestop a macro at opening

Tags: excel, vba

I got a file in task scheduler which has a macro that triggers opening like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call OpenRunMacroandCopy
End Sub
```

A bit like a house alarm, I'd like to have this macro wait before executing the Call for a set duration so I could use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> which i believe would interrupt execution and let me read the file and close it without OpenRunMacroandCopy running at all.

I know of `Application.Wait` and `Sleep` but they don't work here and i do not know why.
I also used `Application.OnTime Now + 5 / 1440, "OpenRunMacroandCopy"` which does seem to make it wait but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> gives me no notification and i've had that macro run anyway so i'm not sure interruption is working? When I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> on an infinite loop macro i do get an error window which is quite nice so i definitely know i have it stopped.
Got an idea, or a more purposeful way to make that happen?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? do you want the macro to stop once the file is open so that you can read it and then have the option to continue the macro or not?

Comment: i want a safe and reliable way to open the file that has a huuuuuge macro at opening to open without triggering that macro when i need

Comment: In your code if you can turn off events (`application.enableevents = false`) to stop the macro running when the file opens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents

Comment: If you just want to open the file without running the macro, you could just hold the "SHIFT" key while opening the file and it will disable the macros

Comment: I also know of the shift key bypass but i swear it doesnt work on this work computer...

Comment: You can use a `Message Box` or `modeless UserForm` to pause the macro's execution.